# error using "find" command in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I was just trying the below code and it is not working.. please suggest to correct this code..

```
echo abc.txt | while read name; do find . -name $name; done
```

output success : ./rak/abc.txt

```
echo 'abc.txt pqr.txt' | while read name; do find . -name $name; done
```

output error : find: 0652-009 There is a missing conjunction

```
echo "abc.txt pqr.txt" | while read name; do find . -name $name; done
```

output error : find: 0652-009 There is a missing conjunction

same error with

```
echo "abc.txt" "pqr.txt" | while read name; do find . -name $name; done
echo 'abc.txt' 'pqr.txt' | while read name; do find . -name $name; done
```

Please suggest how to resolve this problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the multiple entries are sent into the pipe as one line, the read picks up both strings into `name` and then processes the `$name` containing the two strings.

You should use something like:

```
echo -e "abc.txt\npqr.txt" | while read name; do find . -name $name; done
```

i.e. separate the items with a newline.

You should have tried debugging this by using `echo "'$name'"` instead of the `find` and it would have hinted what was happening.

Additionally, I would use quoting around the use of `$name` in the find, as if the filename is expected to have a space in it's name then you will get the same error message as you have experienced originally.

Comment: Thanks for prompt respose.. its working fine now.. tried to give +1 but it required 15 reputation...