# How to get occurrences of word in all files? But with count of the words per directory instead of single number

Tags: linux, unix, aix

I would like to get given word count in all the files but per directory instead of a single count. I do get the word count with simple `grep foo error*.log | wc -l` by going to a specific directory. I would like to get the word count per directory when the directory structure is like below.

```
Directory tree                 
.
├── dir1
│   └── error2.log
    └── error1.log
└── dir2
     └── error_123.log
     └── error_234.log
 ── dir3
     └── error_12345.log
     └── error_23554.log
```

Comment: Maybe you could start with something like this: `wc -w * 2>/dev/null | tail -n1 | { read N _; echo $N; }`

Comment: Can you please clarify and point where we give the word to be searched for?

Comment: For example `grep -- "searchfor" * 2>/dev/null | wc -l | tail -n1` can be used to get the number of lines in all files that contain string _searchfor_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: The following command can be used on AIX:

```
#!/bin/bash

for name in /path/to/folder/* ; do
    if [ ! -d "${name}" ] ; then
        continue
    fi
    # See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398414/45365
    count="$(cat "${name}"/error*.log | tr '[:space:]' '[\n*]' | grep -c 'SEARCH')"
    printf "%s %s\n" "${name}" "${count}"
done
```

---

On GNU/Linux, with GNU `findutils` and GNU `grep`:

```
find /path/to/folder -maxdepth 1 -type d \
    -printf "%p " -exec bash -c 'grep -ro 'SEARCH' {} | wc -l' \;
```

Replace `SEARCH` by the actual search term.

Comment: There is no -maxdepth for AIX, I believe we have to give list of directories for -prune. Tried the command on Linux as well but it didn't work as expected. Anything missing here?

Comment: On AIX there is also no `grep -o`. Then the whole solution is obsolete

Comment: @cnu I've added a command which should work on both GNU/Linux and AIX. Unfortunately I couldn't try it myself on AIX. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Full command produces following error. `find: 0652-009 There is a missing conjunction`. `find /path/to/folder/* -type d -prune -print` part lists out all the directories but not the remaining command. Not sure what the issue is since bash is also installed on AIX.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308436/error-using-find-command-in-unix) helps? Otherwise I need to ask for shell access :)

Comment: Looks like you really need a loop on AIX because find won't consume more than one filename argument. I've changed my answer.

Comment: Yes, the script is giving what I need. Is there a way to restrict the for loop to look at directories in the given path and stop recursive search of all the files/directories?

Comment: Changed the for loop with the directories list with full path with an array and it now looks at given directories only. 

`DIR_LIST=(
    \home\path\dir1
    \home\path\dir2
    \home\path\dir3
)`